# Best way to handle big dynamic form with stages in React?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-forms

I want to make an app where the admins can create "global" forms that other users can fill in. So I need these global forms to be dynamically rendered, and they are kind of big (30+ fields) and are divided in stages (e.g. stage 1 is for personal info, stage 2 is for job skills, etc).
I thought of receiving these "global" forms via `JSON`, something like this:

```
{
  "filledBy":"User",
  "stages":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Personal information",
      "fields":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "type":"email",
          "name":"email",
          "label":"E-mail",
          "placeholder":"name@company.com",
          "value":"",
          "rules":{
            "required":true
          }
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "type":"text",
          "name":"name",
          "label":"Name",
          "placeholder":"John Smith",
          "value":"",
          "pattern":"[A-Za-z]",
          "rules":{
            "required":true,
            "minLength":2,
            "maxLength":15
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Job profile",
      "fields":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "type":"multi",
          "name":"workExperience",
          "subfields":[
            {
              "id":1,
              "type":"text",
              "name":"position",
              "label":"Position",
              "placeholder":"CEO",
              "value":"",
              "rules":{
                "required":true,
                "minLength":3,
                "maxLength":30
              }
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "type":"date",
              "name":"startDate",
              "label":"Starting date",
              "placeholder":"November/2015",
              "value":"",
              "rules":{
                "required":true,
                "minValue":"01/01/1970",
                "maxValue":"today",
                "showAsColumn":true
              }
            },
            {
              "id":3,
              "type":"date",
              "name":"endDate",
              "label":"Ending date",
              "placeholder":"March/2016",
              "value":"",
              "rules":{
                "required":true,
                "minValue":"endDate",
                "maxValue":"today",
                "showAsColumn":true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I created a component called `MasterForm` that first gets the empty form in `componentDidMount()`, like a blueprint. Then, once it is fetched, it tries to get the data entered by the user and put it in the form as the `value` property. After that, it passes the form down to the `Stage` component which renders every field as an `Input` component. That way, `MasterForm` controls the current stage, and allows the user to navigate among stages, and also fetches the data and fills the form. With all the checks and stuff, my `MasterForm` component got very big (around 700 lines), and every time I update the value of a field in the form, I update the whole form object in the state, so I think that might be slow. Also, to fill in the form with the user's data, I have to copy every nested object and array inside the form object, to avoid mutating the state, and that's also very messy (a lot of `const updatedFields = { ...this.state.form.stage.fields }` and stuff).

Are there better ways to do this (preferably without Redux)? How could I decouple this huge `MasterForm` component? Is there a better way to update the form values (other than updating the whole form every time)? or maybe React is smart and doesn't update the whole state, but just the bit that changed... I'm not sure, I'm new to React.

Answer (score 0):

Look into formik https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik and Yup https://github.com/jquense/yup

Here they are coupled together https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#validationschema

Comment: I was trying to understand Formik's code but I think it's too much for me. I'm interested in learning patterns or "best practices" in doing stuff like this. Like rendering a lot of dynamic elements, loading content that's kind of problematic, splitting components, etc. Thanks for the quick solution though :)